# php code exit the loop before it is completed

Tags: php, mysql, curl

i have written a php script to grab data from another site using **CURL**. an uploaded to the server. there is aloop communicating with the database and the relevent url. it is working fine in my local computer. but... the code exist itself before the process complete. i have put `set_time_limit(0);`. but didnt work

it brakes from here when running multiple times

```
$curl_connection =  curl_init("$link");

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);


$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($result);**
```

Comment: It exits because of a timeout?

Comment: This gives us no much information.

Comment: Is it a regular web hosting or is it your own dedicated server or vps? If It's just a web hosting service they might have a time limit that you cant change. What's the output of  `ini_get('max_execution_time')`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared hosting , must shared hosting not work with Curl you need to use your own server to work in perfect mode also please put your code to know more about your problem .

Comment: the program outputs the value. but it is stopping rendering the web page. the webpage is half rendered when the loop stops